# How to retrieve text fields as an array in PHP

Tags: php, post, foreach

I have a form as below which allows users to add more input field through a addmore button . my question is how can i retrieve the array in POST and echo them out . as you can see i have two input fields with name product[] and quantity[] (more fields can be added) . i have to get the value of the field using a a foreach loop and store it in a varibla $message to be used in mail(). i have tried a for each loop for both and my for each loop code as below

```
$product = $_POST['product'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

foreach($product as $value)
{
    $message = "<html><head>
        <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <table> 
            <tr>
                <td>".$value."";
}

foreach($quantity as $value)
{
    $message.=" </td>
                <td>".$value."</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>";
}
```

My input form

```
 <form id="quick_post" method="post"> 
<table id="input_fields">
    <tr> 
        <td><input class="orderinput" type="text" name="product[]" /></td> 
        <td><input class="orderquan" type="text" name="quantity[]" size="1" maxlength="3" /></td>
    </tr>
 </tr>
</table>

<input class="more" type="button" value="Addmore" name="addmore" /> // a jquery script is processed on click to add more fields.       
<input class="send" type="submit" value="Send" name="send" /></form>
```

the output for this is i get only the first row of products printed and for the remaining row only the quantity is printed or echoed. as below

```
Product Name  Quantity
aaaaaa       22 
             33
```

Comment: You have head/title tags etc in your loop, you do not want these repeated

Comment: my attempt is to send a html mail. i think, i can move the html and head tag our of the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your first `foreach` loop you are just overwriting the `$message` variable and the last product name is passed to the second loop.

Try this

```
echo "<html><head><title></title></head> <body> <table>";
for($i=0 ; $i < count($product) ; $i++) 
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$product[$i]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$quantity[$i]."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table></body></html>";
```

Comment: Thanks for that simple code . As a beginner i was messing up everything. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but in the first foreach you may have to need to concate the $message as you have done it for the second foreach of $quantity .

Answer (score 0):

> $product = $_POST['product'];
>
> $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
>
> for($i=0 ; $i < sizeof($product) ; $i++)
>   {

```
        $message.="<tr>
            <td>".$product[$i]."</td>
            <td>".$quantity[$i]."</td>
              </tr>";
```

}

Comment: concate the table start tag to the message variable before loop and table end tag tag after loop